# Why does standard web React MS Bot Framework implementation remove either own or user message?

Tags: reactjs, botframework

My React implementation of the Microsoft Bot Framework as described in the "Integrate with React" section on [its github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) has two peculiar behaviors (recording can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5ebrbnd1rk0b38/react-bot-video.mov?dl=0)), and happens both locally and when deployed:

1. The reponse message is shown for 1/10 second, then disappears. User message is still shown.
2. The response message is shown, but the user message is deleted

My set-up is as follows:

1. I use the [CART framework](https://github.com/uvacw/CART) to set up the bot
2. This utilizes an AWS RDS db, the MS Azure Chatbot, the dialog flow is from dialogflow. The backend is provided by CART. I added an API for the authentication of the chatbot (to get the token)
3. The chatbot is hosted on a separate static react app with the following dependencies and versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "botframework-directlinejs": "^0.11.6",
    "botframework-webchat": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  }
```

I checked the following:

1. When showing the chat with the iframe provided by MS, the chat works as expected.
2. The backend gives successful responses for each of the behaviors above, so from a backend perspective there seems to be no difference

Therefore, I believe it has something to do with the React implementation which seems to be out of my control.

Hoping this is a known issue with a solution.

EDIT: I now copied https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/10.a.customization-card-components and I still have the displaying issue when adding the token that connects to my bot.
Additionally, I now log the cards that my middleware gets. When I send a single message "hi", I get **four** objects:

1. the object 'hi' that I sent
2. The returned object from dialogflow with the response
3. An exact copy of 2, with same ID and timestamp
4. An object that looks like a response, but contains the message the user sent

Which is different from the standard implementation with the MS bot, which gets (when sending 'hi') **seven** 'cards':

1. The message 'hi', status is sending
2. Copy of 1.
3. Message returned by bot ('hi' not available, type 'help')
4. A message returned by bot with the content of what the user sent ('hi')
5. Copy of 3.
6. Copy of 4.
7. Copy of 3.

I am assuming that these in some way get overwritten. The MS implementation 'ends' with the bot message, while mine 'ends' with the user message.

Answer (score 0):

This setup works in my React project:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactWebChat, { createDirectLine } from 'botframework-webchat';

export default class WebChatView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      directLine: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchToken();
  }
  async fetchToken() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3500/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
    const { token } = await res.json();

    this.setState(() => ({
      directLine: createDirectLine({ token })
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.directLine ?
        <ReactWebChat
          directLine={this.state.directLine}
        />
        :
        <div>Connecting to bot&hellip;</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope of help!

---

### Edit

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "reactbot",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "botframework-webchat": "^4.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "restify": "^8.4.0",
    "restify-cors-middleware": "^1.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "serviceworker-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives me the same behavior. What is the content of your package.json? How did you program the responses of your bot?

Comment: @YoniSchirris, I added the `package.json`. Also, I used "create-react-app", should that matter. Are any of the packages installed globally, as well? Perhaps a package is defaulting to a global install...?

Comment: Reinstalling node_modules with your package.json and using your code interestingly still presents the buggy messaging.

How do you do your conversation handling? I have a backend that communicates between the microsoft bot framework and dialogflow, though I believe that this works well as the bot framework iframe works well, just the React implementation works wrongly.

Comment: I'm not using dialogflow, just the MS BotFramework for conversation handling. I'm not all that familiar with dialogflow, but I have some colleagues that are. Can you post your code regarding the backend communication between the two, etc.?

Comment: I've implemented github.com/uvacw/CART according to their docs: cart.readthedocs.io/en/latest. Pretty much everything happens in github.com/uvacw/CART/blob/master/tasks.py. I will now dive into trying to see if the issue is in DialogFlow response timing, or whether it's caused by the CART backend. The function "echo_response" is added as a process to the MSBot connection. This is implemented according to https://microsoftbotframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Interestingly, when I implement the simple 'echo_response' code (immeditaly return same message as reply), I get the same behavior